# Problems with UpdateView in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

I've looked on this site for help with UpdateView, and while I've found content dealing with setting it up, I am having trouble making it happen myself. I'm not sure what the problem is, and at this point rather than continue to tear my hair out I figured someone here could easily spot my mistake.

I'm trying to have a list of teams, with edit buttons to the right of them. Whenever an edit button is clicked, it's supposed to take the user to a page where the fields of that particular team model can be updated.
Whenever I click on the edit button in the code below, I get a NoReverseMatch error. What am I doing wrong?

The view.py code:

```
class TeamUpdate(UpdateView):
model = Team
fields = ['team_name', 'sport', 'sport_season']
```

The url.py code:

```
 url(r'(?P<name>[0-9]+d)/$', TeamUpdate.as_view(), name='team_update'),
```

The relevant template code:

```
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
        <table class="table">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Team Name</th>
                <th>Sport</th>
                <th>Season</th>
                <th>Preferences</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for team in teams %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{team}}</td>
                <td>{{team.sport_verbose}}</td>
                <td>{{team.season_verbose}}</td>
                <td> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href = '{% url "team_update" team.team_name %}' value="Edit" ></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
```

Edit:
so I changed my regex to  `url(r'(?P<name>)$', TeamUpdate.as_view(), name='team_update'),` 
from what was above, figuring that this would substitute the name of the team into the url, but the same NoReverseMatch error is coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex looks broken. It only matches one or more digits followed by a literal 'd'. I suspect your team names don't match that pattern.

Comment: What would you suggest as a fix? I based it off of several other stackoverflow responses. Do you have any good resources for best practices on regex?

Comment: Depends on the format of your name field. `r'(?P<name>\w+)/$'` would work if it's just alphanumeric characters.